# Determining when a process has finalized initialization

Tags: c#, python, ironpython

I'm building an IronPython module that initializes an instance of AutoCAD and I need to return 1 to the module calling it *after* AutoCAD has finished initializing, entered its message loop and is in a stable (not loading dependencies/anything) state. I've tried using `System.Diagnostics.Process.WaitForInputIdle()` with no luck.

Here's what I have so far:

```
import System.Diagnostics as sysdiag

def start_autocad(self):
    print("\"C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Autodesk AutoCAD Civil 3D 2014\\acad.exe\" /b \"C:\\Temp\\C3DAutoScript.scr\"")
    for process in sysdiag.Process.GetProcessesByName("acad"):
        process.Kill()
    try:
        acad_process = sysdiag.Process.Start("C:\\Program Files\\Autodesk\\Autodesk AutoCAD Civil 3D 2014\\acad.exe", " /b \"C:\\Temp\\C3DAutoScript.scr\"")
        acad_process.WaitForInputIdle()
        return 1
    except:
        return 0
```

Unfortunately, this function as it stands returns as soon as the process begins opening, not after it's done. Does anyone know a way to handle this either in classic cPython, IronPython or C# (without using an overkill sleep function to wait for it)?

Answer (score 1):

A process can start processing messages almost immediately after start up. There is no requirement that the main window is displayed before this is done. This can be done to avoid being displayed as hanging, in case loading is slow.

You can either try interacting with the process after `WaitForInputIdle` returns — it may eventually respond even while "loading". If it doesn't work, wait for the main window to appear (using `FindWindow`). If the application is COM server, you try establishing COM connection.

P.S. Killing processes is not the best idea and may result in corrupted data or configuration. Try closing application properly be sending close event to its main window.

Comment: Is there any way to tell once it is done loading completely? This is to ensure that I do not try to send commands to the process if it fails at any point in the initialization. The above code is part of a complicated automated QA test and I cant afford to have any unhandled exceptions.

Comment: It's an automated test so it really doesn't matter if the process config or data is corrupted. The resulting files have no significance other than the test they are helping run.

Comment: @BadKarma If the process starts responding to events while being in the "loading" state, there's no general way provided by OS to determine when the process stops loading, AFAIK. The question is, does interaction with the process fail if you do it after `WaitForInputIdle` returns?

Comment: Well maybe there's a workaround? Part of the problem here is that I cannot send my specific commands to the ACAD command line prior to it finalizing initialization. Many dependencies I use are loaded in the middle of opening the program (after the command line opens for input). So it is very possible for me to see errors if I return too soon.

Comment: @BadKarma There's no general way provided by OS. There may be ways specific to AutoCAD. A quick Google search shows that you can try [waiting for AutoCAD's COM object availability](http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2007/12/launching-aut-1.html), for example. You can also try searching for specific windows, like I've mentioned in the answer.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to do it from Python/MSDN .NET Libraries/IronPython. The other option would be to write a quick pass/fail file for python to read from my C# AutoCAD plugin. However, I'd like to avoid this if possible as it would be a rather inefficient solution.

Comment: @BadKarma What "processor error"? Maybe it's just apartment state issue? If it's CLR object, IronPython can interact with it, it can't be "built exclusively for C#". Anyway, it's a different issue which isn't even mentioned in the question.

Comment: Its due to the fact that IronPython is compiled in x86 as its only option and AutoCAD is either x32 or x64.

Answer (score 0):

In the title of your question you ask for "a process". In the text of your question you ask specifically for Autocad.

I can tell you how to do it for a process in general, not specifically for Autocad.

I had the same problem and came to the solution to use the API

```
GetModuleFileNameEx(HANDLE h_Process, ....)
```

MSDN says:

> If the module list in the target process is corrupted or is **not yet
>   initialized**, or if the module list changes during the function call as
>   a result of DLLs being loaded or unloaded, GetModuleFileNameEx may
>   fail or return incorrect information.

And in deed when you try to get the executable path of the process with this function while the process is still loading it's DLL's the function fails and `GetLastError()` returns `ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE`. This does not mean that the process handle that you pass to the function is invalid. But this is the error code you get when the process is still starting up.

I tested it with several applications. It works perfectly.

```
int WaitForProcess(HANDLE h_Process, int Timeout)
{
    for (int T=0; T<=Timeout; T+=50)
    {
       if (GetModuleFileNameEx(h_Process, NULL, ...) > 0)
           return 0;

       int Err = GetLastError();
       if (Err != ERROR_INVALID_HANDLE) // = 6
           return Err;

       Sleep(50);
    }
    return ERROR_TIMEOUT;
}
```

Why does it work? What GetModuleFileNameEx() does internally is to read the memory of the process (for that you must open the process with access permission PROCESS_VM_READ). But this is not allowed while the process is in the loader lock. The loader lock is active while a process is loading DLL's.

This code is general and works for any application. It waits until the application is ready with it's basic initialization. If this is not enough for you I recommend to wait for the main window of the application to appear.